# Executing Code On All Cells, In All Sheets, In Entire Workbook

Tags: vba, excel

My issue is that I'm trying to create a code that will change a cell value to an "X" if it contains a value, every cell across multiple sheets needs to be checked (I'm very aware this may take a long time!).

This application is for a huge matrix where the "structure" is more important that the actual values. It's complicated and very difficult to explain (it's created by a 3rd party and **very** old system and then exported to excel)

I'm sure im along the right lines, but this just doesnt work, I get a "method not supported" fault on line `For Each Cell In ws`

```
Sub Usage_X()

Dim ws As Worksheet

For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
ws.Activate
    For Each Cell In ws
        If Cell.Value <> "" Then
            Cell.Value = "X"
        End If
    Next
Next


End Sub
```

Comment: Try `For each c as Cell in ws`{http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/5ebk1751.aspx]

Comment: You need to say `Next Cell` and `Next ws`, not just `Next`.

Comment: @Roland `For each c as Cell in ws` is not valid

Comment: @MattCremeens although you are correct and I missed that, it doesnt solve the code breaking at `For Each cell In ws`

Comment: sorry. it should be `For each Cell in ws.Cells`

Comment: @Roland What should be `Range`? Please post the code as I'm having difficulty understanding where you're talking about

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you need to loop through each cell in a range, not in a sheet. So modify to read

```
Sub Usage_X()

Dim ws As Worksheet

For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
Set rng = ws.UsedRange
    For Each Cell In rng
        If Cell.Value <> "" Then
            Cell.Value = "X"
        End If
    Next Cell
Next ws


End Sub
```

Comment: Works flawlessly. I've never thought about using `UsedRange`! Thanks